# .htacces not working on rewrite localhost and webhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an index.php where i've setted $_GET['titluri']; variable and echo it:

```
 if(isset($_GET['titluri'])){
   $preluare = $_GET['titluri'];
 } else $preluare = null;

   echo 'Aici va aparea + ',$preluare;
```

All I want is to manipulate the `$_GET` using `.htacces` rewrite rule.

Here is my failing code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^topic/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?titluri=$1
```

What is wrog? I've tried on webhost to! (My tests are maded on Xamp Windows on my PC)

Comment: You never say what the actual problem is. All we know is that you have a problem.

Comment: The problem is that url rewrite not working, so if i acces `localhost/titluri/test` instead of `localhost/index.php?titluri=test` i get `Object not found (404 err)`

Answer (score 0):

Without providing more context my best bet would be to remove the / I.e.
RewriteRule ^topic/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?titluri=$1
Depending on how you call your page this might cause problems with the rewriting. Also I'm assuming this is just the word wrapping on my screen but the entire rewrite rule has to be on one line.

Comment: Or if you want to have the trailing '/' be optional, use `^topic/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$`